# Unable to bind property with color attribute of SolidColorBrush in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

Hi I am trying to bind property in color attribute of SolidColorBrush to change the color at runtime but I am not getting any color even in the property value is coming.

Here the porperty:

```
   public static string mycolor { get; set; } = "Red"
```

Below is my XAML:

```
<my:FlipViewItemControl  x:Name="myflipView" FlipView="{Binding ElementName=flipView}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"
                Margin="0">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                <StackPanel x:Name="ScrollListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush  Color="{Binding mycolor, Mode=OneWay}" Opacity="0.9"></SolidColorBrush>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </my:FlipViewItemControl>
```

Please help me with the issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Color property of SolidCOlorBrush is of Color type, so you should use

```
public static Color mycolor { get; set; } = Colors.Red
```

In XAML you can just write "red" as text and it is handled for you behind the scenes.

Another option would be to add IValueCOnverter to your binding if, for some reason, you need it to be a plain string.

Comment: Thanks Maxim but the given solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to bind property with color attribute of SolidColorBrush in xaml

If you just want to change the `ItemsPanel` color,  set a fix value for the `StackPanel` in XAML. You don't need binding to do this since there is only one `ItemsPanel` in above control. If you do need to use binding to implement this, binding code should as follows:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel
        x:Name="ScrollListBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.9" Color="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel.Background>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Code behind

```
 public static string mycolor { get; set; } = "Red";  
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = mycolor;
     ...
 }
```

More details please reference [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

The `ItemsPanelTemplate` of [`ItemsPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel) defines the panel to use for the layout of the items, not for every item. If you want every item in the list binding with the color property, you should set the binding inside [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemTemplate). For example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myflipView" Margin="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel
                x:Name="ScrollListBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.9" Color="{Binding mycolor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel
                x:Name="ScrollListBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.9" Color="Azure" />
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```